# Why isn't my BEGIN command working on SQL

Tags: postgresql, syntax, command, syntax-error

I have this code to create a function. But it tells me the command in BEGIN is wrong

```
CREATE FUNCTION transform_activebool(activebool CHAR(1)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
BEGIN
    IF activebool = 't' THEN
        RETURN 'Active';
    ELSE
        RETURN 'Inactive';
    END IF;
END;
```

[Code error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OcZ5.png)

I tried moving the syntax and looking at the `BEGIN` command and it's not working.

Comment: you need to use `DELIMITER $$` and add the end `DELIMITER ;`

Comment: Which DBMS is this ?

Comment: It is on postgreSQL /pgADmin

Comment: The syntax is all wrong. Look at the documentation and the examples therein.

Comment: Assuming you are trying to use `plpgsql` then look at [Structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION transform_activebool(activebool CHAR(1)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
    IF activebool = 't' THEN
        RETURN 'Active';
    ELSE
        RETURN 'Inactive';
    END if;
END;
$$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use valid syntax. In this case you can use a simple SQL function, using a CASE to select the correct output:

```
CREATE FUNCTION transform_activebool(activebool CHAR(1)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
LANGUAGE SQL -- you always have to define the language
STRICT -- RETURNS NULL on NULL input
IMMUTABLE -- always returns the same output for the same input
AS
$$ -- function body starts here:
    SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN activebool = 't' 
                THEN 'Active'
            ELSE    'Inactive'
        END CASE;
$$; -- end of the function body

-- test:
SELECT transform_activebool('t') -- Active
    , transform_activebool('x') -- Inactive
    , transform_activebool(NULL); -- NULL
```

This function is so simple, there is no need for the plpgsql language and thus no need for BEGIN and END.